# Assigning a Select field value in a Lightbox form to a php variable, before form submission

Tags: javascript, php, drop-down-menu, lightbox

I am using a lightbox form with a drop-down list. When I choose a value from the dropdown list, I want it to be assigned to a php variable which I will then use to update the total price of the form (the total price is already defined in the form). Here is the link to the relevant page: https://mobilitypro.eu/course/e-learning-blended-learning-and-introduction-to-web-designing/ . When the user clicks Book Now, the lightbox form appears. The problem is with the dropdown list "Select package": when an option is selected, I cannot pass its numerical value to a php variable (before submitting the form). I tried with Ajax to send the value to another php file, but it did not work. Here below is my code, as well as some related pre-existing code of the lightbox-form. I look forward to your help, as I have been trying to find a solution for a long time.

```
<script>
function getval(sel)  
{
   var singleValues = sel.value;

   var price = <?php echo $price ?> * singleValues; 
   alert(price); //this is working

} 
</script>

<p class="gdlr-lms-half-right">
<span><?php _e('Select package*', 'gdlr-lms'); ?></span>
<select id="package" onchange="getval(this);">
            <option value="1">Package 1</option>
            <option value="1.5">Package 2</option>
            <option value="2.55">Package 3</option>
 </select>
 </p>
<?php $price=$price ?> //this is not working
```

Pre-existing code **preceding** my code:

```
        <?php
        $price = empty($course_option['discount-price'])? $course_option['price']: $course_option['discount-price'];
        $price = floatval($price);
    ?>
```

Pre-existing code **following** my code:

```
<p class="gdlr-lms-half-right">
<?php _e('Total Price', 'gdlr-lms'); ?>
<input type="text" class="price-display" value="<?php echo gdlr_lms_money_format(($price * $fix_val['amount']) - $fix_val['coupon-discount']); ?>" disabled />
<input type="hidden" class="price" name="price" value="<?php echo (($price * $fix_val['amount']) - $fix_val['coupon-discount']); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" class="price-one" name="amount" value="<?php echo $price; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" class="format" value="<?php echo $lms_money_format; ?>" />
</p>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what about ajax didn't work, but that was the right solution. PHP executes on the server, so data has to get there for it to be accessible via PHP. So you can either submit the form or use AJAX

Comment: @JoseFernandoLopezFernandez, there are many posts about how to use Ajax, and I tried many suggestions. Nothing worked, and I don't know why. Maybe the fact that the form is in a popup lightbox makes it not work?